# Can anyone help me with this task or explain how to do it?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having trouble with this assignment. Can someone help or explain it to me how i need to finish it?

This is the assignment : Write a program that shortens by an ordered array of elements that occur multiple times, to remove the duplicates, so ultimately each element occurs only once. 
We do not use Sort and we do not generate new array.

I tried multiple times, filling the array is no problem but the rest is.

Here is some of my work :

```
        //aanmaken en vullen van de array
        int[] getallen = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6 };

        //in volgende loop geven we de getallen weer uit de originele array
        for (int teller = 0; teller < 10; teller++)
        {
            Console.Write(getallen[teller] + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("==> ");
        Console.Write(getallen[0] + " ");

        //in volgende loop geven we enkel de unieke getallen uit de array 
        weer
        for (int teller = 1; teller < 10; teller++)
        {
            if (getallen[teller] != getallen[teller - 1])
            {
                Console.Write(getallen[teller] + " ");

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

So it should be :  input: int[] getallen = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6 }; output: {1,2,3,4,5,6}

Comment: @WannesColman - you should not(ideally) use arrays to remove those duplicates.  You have to use some data types that determines size dynamically.  Say for eg., a List, Stack or Queue.  If you have to do it with arrays, we have to compare the value with previous or next value.

Comment: Dreadful title -  a down vote magnet, for sure.  [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` as the results (i.e. remove duplicate adjacent entries), consider this approach:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<int> RemoveDuplicates(int[] input)
        {
            int? old = null;

            foreach (var value in input)
            {
                if (value != old)
                    yield return value;

                old = value;
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            int[] getallen = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6 };
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", RemoveDuplicates(getallen)));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

`IEnumerable<int>` returns the values without using an array, and `yield return` is used to return the non-duplicate entries, one at a time.

`value` is compared to `old` to ensure that duplicate adjacent entries are ignored.

`string.Join` is used to concatenate the values together with a `,` between them, so they print nicely on the console.

*Performance wise, changing the `old` declaration to `int old = (input?.FirstOrDefault() ?? 1) + 1;` may also help, so that nullable types aren't involved. I prefer leaving it as a nullable type for clarity though).*

Comment: I post this, knowing it may possibly not help the OP who may not understand some of these constructs. But I leave it here for future readers, who have more advanced C# skills, that it may be of value to them.

Comment: Thanks so much and also a thank you for explaining what you did. But you are right i don't fully understand.

Comment: @JSteward `Distinct` will actually store the results in memory in a data structure which is very similar to a `HashSet` (i.e. `Distinct`'s RAM usage for a large input array will be considerably larger than using my approach here). `yield return` won't do that. It returns them one at a time @JSteward. Additionally, `Distinct` likely uses an array internally (I haven't checked recently, but I think the `Set` implementation it uses internally uses arrays) - so I wasn't sure how pedantic the professor would be, so I just avoided it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ShortenArray()
{
    int[] getallen = new int[] { 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 6 };
    getallen = getallen.ToList().Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

Explanation:

The Linq-List provides the method Distinct(). This method removes the duplicates, but keeps the order. Further, Linq gives you the ability to convert arrays to list and vice versa.

An alternative way of doing this is to check every item in the array if it is already set before, replace the items in the way, that all the 'empty' values are at the end and use the *Array.Resize(/**/)* method to shorten the array. It's a lot more work to achieve the same result.